# The first and second derivative of mathematical expectation

Tags: probability, derivatives, expected-value

As we know, we could write mathematical expectation based on cumulative distribution function $(F)$ as follow:
$E(x)=\int[1-F(x)]d(x) $

I have the mathematical expectation of a function $p(t)$ based on cumulative distribution function $(F)$ as follow:
$E(p(t))=\int[1-F(p(t))]d(p(t)) $

($p(t)$ is a positive and differentiable function and monotonically increasing in variable $t$)

Now I want to differentiate above equation based on $t$.

Would you tell me what the first and second derivative will be based on t?

$\frac{dE(p(t))}{dt}=?$ and $\frac{d^2E(p(t))}{dt^2}=?$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [derivative of mathematical expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429662/derivative-of-mathematical-expectation)

Comment: Description is muddy.  What are the limits of integration?  What is the $x$ in $E(x)$?  Usually $E(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdF(x)$, where $F(x)$ is cdf for the random variable $A$.

Comment: x is a random variable. In my problem, t is a random variable that follows a probability distribution function (PDF).